# Post-registration action in ServiceStack

Tags: .net, authentication, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I have used ServiceStack for a few projects and really love it. That said, this is my first foray into dealing with user auth in any way, so forgive me if I'm making any fundamental errors in my understanding or implementation here.

I need to be able to track custom properties for users, such as their user type and the company they are associated with. To do this, I have created a separate "User" class that contains just the details about the user that I want to track, plus the custom bits. I like this because, for example, I can store the UserTypeId as a property of User, and [Reference] the actual UserType object. This let's me send that nested data back to the client using LoadReferences elsewhere in the service code.

In order to do any of that, I need to get the custom User object to send back to the browser (it's a web app). So far, I have implemented a CustomCredentialsAuthProvider that adds the User object to the AuthResponse like this:

```
public override object Authenticate(IServiceBase authService, IAuthSession session, Authenticate request)
    {
        //let normal authentication happen
        var authResponse = (AuthenticateResponse)base.Authenticate(authService, session, request);

        using (var db = authService.TryResolve<IDbConnectionFactory>().OpenDbConnection())
        {
            User user = db.LoadSingleById<User>(int.Parse(authResponse.UserId));

            //return your own class, but take neccessary data from AuthResponse
            return new
            {
                SessionId = authResponse.SessionId,
                ReferrerUrl = authResponse.ReferrerUrl,
                ResponseStatus = authResponse.ResponseStatus,
                UserSession = user
            };
        }
    }
```

This works well. To handle User Profile management in the app, I post any needed updates that get written to both the User table as well as the IUserAuthRepository (both using the current session UserAuthId as the key).

OK, that's all the groundwork. What I need to do now, if possible, is allow User A to register another User B without switching their session over to User B. As far as I can tell, the Register method returns only the user ID that was just created...

```
{"userId":"1019","responseStatus":{}}
```

...and also sets the session cookie to the newly created user session. I guess I need a way to prevent this automatic session assignment, and to be able to just register new users and get their ID independently of anything else. Is that possible?

On a related note, I'd like to be able to retrieve the entire user profile back immediately after registration, not just the "userId". As it stands right now, I need to do another server call right away to get the User details (pulled from User based on the session.UserAuthId).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Customizing Authenticate Service Response

I would recommend that you always return a concrete class in ServiceStack Services (i.e. instead of an anonymous object) this helps with being able to generate metadata services for the DTO types and lets you deserialize the response in typed APIs.

You should also consider adhering to the `Authenticate` service contract (that all clients expect) and continue to return an `AuthenticateResponse` type. You can use the `Dictionary<string,string> Meta` property to attach additional metadata to the return type, e.g:

```
var r = (AuthenticateResponse)base.Authenticate(authService, session, request);

using (var db = authService.TryResolve<IDbConnectionFactory>().Open())
{
    User user = db.LoadSingleById<User>(int.Parse(r.UserId));

    r.Meta = new Dictionary<String,String> {
        {"customId", user.CustomId},
        //etc
    };

    return r;
}
```

Your Service will still work if you choose to return a different type, but in this way it wont break .NET Service Clients who are expecting to receive a typed `AuthenticateResponse`.

### Custom Registration implementation

For the Custom Registration instead of using the existing [RegisterService](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Auth/RegisterService.cs) implementation take a copy and create your own version that does what you want.

The Register Services uses the the `IAuthRepository` dependency to create new users:

```
public IAuthRepository AuthRepo { get; set; }
```

Which it casts to an [IUserAuthRepository](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Auth/IAuthRepository.cs#L19) so it can access the richer APIs, e.g:

```
var userAuthRepo = AuthRepo.AsUserAuthRepository(GetResolver());
```

Here you can register a new user by populating an instance of the [UserAuth](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Auth/UserAuth.cs) class, e.g:

```
var newUserAuth = request.ConvertTo<UserAuth>();
newUserAuth.PrimaryEmail = request.Email;
```

Which you can use to create a new user with:

```
userAuthRepo.CreateUserAuth(newUserAuth, request.Password)
```

Which just persists the new `UserAuth` info into the registered `IUserAuthRepository`.

As you're now using your own Register class implementation it wont affect your existing Session and you can return whatever response you like.

Comment: This got me going down the right path. I implemented a CustomRegistration service that let's me do both things I need: 1) let a user register themselves, auto-log them in and return the custom User object in the response, and 2) allow a user to register someone else and just get back the custom User Id and DisplayName. Works great.